# Is there a way to call a Business Process BPMN in a Test Scenario?

Tags: redhat-brms

In Decision Central 7.2 is there a way to invoke a .bpmn / Business Process in a Legacy Test Scenario (.scenario)?

Comment: My bad. The release notes of changes and additions claim that this feature is added in v 7.4

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no such feature.